# Convert Varchar to double

Tags: sql, db2, varchar

I have this data in a `varchar` column which have sign at the end of the number and would like to convert to numeric and the sign will have to reflect in the final result e.g 91.99- should be -91.99

Sample data

```
Curr_bal
934.75+
9123.05+
91.99-
9.77-
```

How do I convert and handle this 2 scenarios using SQL command. really need your help.
by the way, i am try to write SQL for DB2.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: I'm sure a combination of `substr()`, `concat()` and `to_number()` (or the equivalent) should do the trick.

Comment: i am new to this DB2 SQL, do not what to do. Appreciate if somebody can give me a sample coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr() and length() to extract the sign (last character) and value (first through second to last characters) from the varchar.  Then use the concatenation operator to glue it back together with the sign at the front.  Like so:

```
db2 => select curr_bal, substr(curr_bal,length(curr_bal),1) || substr(curr_bal,1,length(curr_bal)-1) from signswap;

CURR_BAL                         2                                
-------------------------------- ---------------------------------
934.75+                          +934.75                          
9123.05+                         +9123.05                         
91.99-                           -91.99                           
9.77-                            -9.77                            

  4 record(s) selected.

db2 =>
```

Once you have it with the sign at the front, you can cast it as numeric, or in some cases DB2 will cast it for your.  For example, you can insert it into a another table with numeric type column without explicitly casting it:

```
db2 => create table numeric(curr_bal decimal(12,2));
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => insert into numeric select substr(curr_bal,length(curr_bal),1) || substr(curr_bal,1,length(curr_bal)-1) from signswap;
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => select * from numeric;

CURR_BAL      
--------------
        934.75
       9123.05
        -91.99
         -9.77

  4 record(s) selected.

db2 =>
```

Comment: tqvm @KevinBeck, really appreciate it:)